# Picasa email photo not working on Mac

Tags: mac, thunderbird, picasa

I am using thunderbird and when I click on the email photo button nothing happens.

How can I get the email photo button to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Mac mail but not any other non-Mac options.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird on the Mac does not provide a way for other applications to create a new mail message with attachments so it is not possible to do this. (See [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=15701ddf41decfcc&hl=en) in the Picasa for Mac help forum)

Comment: It looks like I might have to configure Mac mail to get it to work.

Comment: Yes it is unfortunate. I had the same problem with iPhoto not being able to send mail via Thunderbird.